# elasticsearch helm charts (from elastic or bitnami) don't work with k3s

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm, elastic-stack, bitnami, k3s

Gooday everybody.

For a week I've been unsuccessfully trying to spin an elastic cluster on the latest k3s v1.21.3+k3s1. Both bitnami/elasticsearch and elastic elastic/elasticsearch don't work although with different errors.

The thing is I've tried to spin an elastic cluster in a k3s on absolutely clean VMs:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Ubuntu 21.04
- Debian 10.10
- from 1 core cpu, 4Gb of RAM and 30Gb storage to 4 cpu, 16Gb and 60Gb storage(at first I thought I might be a requirements issue)
- from 1 node to a full k3s cluster with 3 nodes

At the same time, both charts span like a charm the first time I tried them inside minikube. All the config always default. Please help, I've lost hope...

**Here is an error log of a master pod from the bitnami/elasticsearch chart:**

```
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.59 [0m
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.60 [0m[1mWelcome to the Bitnami elasticsearch container[0m
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.60 [0mSubscribe to project updates by watching [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-elasticsearch[0m
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.60 [0mSubmit issues and feature requests at [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-elasticsearch/issues[0m
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.60 [0m
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.61 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting Elasticsearch setup **
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.65 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring/Initializing Elasticsearch...
ls: cannot open directory '/bitnami/elasticsearch/data': Permission denied
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.72 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Setting default configuration
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:02:56.76 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring Elasticsearch cluster settings...
warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
warning: usage of JAVA_HOME is deprecated, use ES_JAVA_HOME
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:03:10.86 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Elasticsearch setup finished! **

[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m15:03:10.91 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting Elasticsearch **
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2021-08-26T15:03:20,716][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elasticsearch-1629989764-master-0] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/bitnami/elasticsearch/data)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/bitnami/elasticsearch/data)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:61) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:208) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:399) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /bitnami/elasticsearch/data
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:208) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:399) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    ... 6 more
uncaught exception in thread [main]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/bitnami/elasticsearch/data)
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /bitnami/elasticsearch/data
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:313)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:208)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:399)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:81)
For complete error details, refer to the log at /opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/logs/elastic.log
```

**Here is an error log of a master pod from the elastic/elasticsearch chart:**

```
    {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-08-26T14:42:43,598Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-2", "message": "uncaught exception in thread [main]", 
    "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:61) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:208) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:399) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "... 6 more",
    "Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
    "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]",
    "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106) ~[?:?]",
    "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]",
    "at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:313) ~[?:?]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:208) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:399) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]",
    "... 6 more"] }
    uncaught exception in thread [main]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)
    Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:313)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:208)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:155)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:214)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:399)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:81)
    For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log
```

**An error log of a master pod from the bitnami/elasticsearch chart with volumePermissions.enabled set to true**

```
[38;5;6melasticsearch [38;5;5m09:29:07.85 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting Elasticsearch **
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2021-08-27T09:29:15,892Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elastic", "node.name": "elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0", "message": "[transport.tcp.port] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version." }
[2021-08-27T09:29:16,900][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] version[7.14.0], pid[1], build[default/tar/dd5a0a2acaa2045ff9624f3729fc8a6f40835aa1/2021-07-29T20:49:32.864135063Z], OS[Linux/5.11.0-31-generic/amd64], JVM[BellSoft/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.12/11.0.12+7-LTS]
[2021-08-27T09:29:16,900][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] JVM home [/opt/bitnami/java], using bundled JDK [false]
[2021-08-27T09:29:16,903][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-11225315085643140958, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Xms128m, -Xmx128m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=67108864, -Des.path.home=/opt/bitnami/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2021-08-27T09:29:32,359Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elastic", "node.name": "elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0", "message": "[gateway.recover_after_nodes] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version." }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2021-08-27T09:29:32,369Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elastic", "node.name": "elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0", "message": "[discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version." }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2021-08-27T09:29:32,371Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elastic", "node.name": "elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0", "message": "[gateway.expected_nodes] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version." }
[2021-08-27T09:29:38,041][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] parsed [0] roles from file [/opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]
[2021-08-27T09:29:39,856][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseRegistry ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] initialized database registry, using geoip-databases directory [/tmp/elasticsearch-11225315085643140958/geoip-databases/T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA]
[2021-08-27T09:29:42,077][INFO ][o.e.t.NettyAllocator     ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=false, g1gc_region_size=0b, heap_size=123.7mb}]
[2021-08-27T09:29:42,373][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2021-08-27T09:29:43,423][INFO ][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
[2021-08-27T09:29:44,313][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] initialized
[2021-08-27T09:29:44,319][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] starting ...
[2021-08-27T09:29:45,354][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2021-08-27T09:29:50,393][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5s/5054ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-master.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:29:50,394][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5s/5054ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-coordinating-only.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:29:50,394][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5s/5054ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-data.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:30:05,390][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-1, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2021-08-27T09:30:05,435][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] failed to resolve host [elasticsearch-1630056078-master.default.svc.cluster.local]
java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch-1630056078-master.default.svc.cluster.local
    at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:883) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:563) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:505) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:967) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.SeedHostsResolver.lambda$resolveHostsLists$0(SeedHostsResolver.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:673) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:673) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
[2021-08-27T09:30:15,395][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-1, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2021-08-27T09:30:20,552][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5s/5091ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-master.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:30:20,552][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5s/5091ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-coordinating-only.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:30:20,553][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5s/5091ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-data.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:30:25,398][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-1, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2021-08-27T09:30:35,403][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-1, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2021-08-27T09:30:35,580][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] failed to resolve host [elasticsearch-1630056078-coordinating-only.default.svc.cluster.local]
java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch-1630056078-coordinating-only.default.svc.cluster.local
    at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:563) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:505) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:967) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.SeedHostsResolver.lambda$resolveHostsLists$0(SeedHostsResolver.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:673) ~[elasticsearch-7.14.0.jar:7.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
[2021-08-27T09:30:55,417][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-1, elasticsearch-1630056078-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0}{T5RcvZGLRleO990MCvjsPA}{eoQgmlhCQzK29BLWrUGe_Q}{10.42.1.54}{10.42.1.54:9300}{mr}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2021-08-27T09:30:55,634][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [4.8s/4857ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-master.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:30:55,634][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [4.8s/4857ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-coordinating-only.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:30:55,634][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [4.8s/4857ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-data.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:31:00,654][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5.1s/5116ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-master.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:31:00,654][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5.1s/5116ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-coordinating-only.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:31:00,654][WARN ][o.e.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] timed out after [5.1s/5116ms] ([discovery.seed_resolver.timeout]=[5s]) resolving host [elasticsearch-1630056078-data.default.svc.cluster.local]
[2021-08-27T09:31:04,380][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elasticsearch-1630056078-master-0] stopping ...
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the pvc setup in k3s, where the data dir that's mounted in the pods does not have the proper permissions. Can you try to run the bitnami/elasticsearch helm install with the parameter `volumePermissions.enabled` set to `true` and check if that does anything? ( see here for reference: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/elasticsearch#volumepermissions-parameters )

Comment: Thank you for the response. So it did change a lot, but elastic still won't start though.

All data and master pods received an additional init container called "volume permissions"

The error is different now, ill add it to the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although "change the k3s version" is not an answer to the problem per se, this issue seems related to the specific `v1.21.3+k3s1` version. I've tried the default installation of the `bitnami/elasticsearch` chart on these:

```
v1.18.20-k3s1: OK
v1.19.14-k3s1: OK
v1.20.10+k3s1: OK
v1.21.3-k3s1: KO
v1.21.4-k3s1: OK
v1.22.1-rc1-k3s1: OK
```

My guess is that it is related to this issue: [[Backport 1.21] Cannot write data to local PVC](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/pull/3721)

Comment: You've done all that? Awesome work, i'll check it!

However, how to install v1.21.4-k3s1 or v1.22.1-rc1-k3s1? Are those from the future?:)

Comment: I think you are right on point! I decided not to mention one thing, but it turned out to be crucial: I have had one success with elastic install on one of my test servers, but I thought it was just luck or something. I checked the version of k3s on that server - it's 1.21.2...makes sense now.

Comment: I used a little trick, k3d + images from https://hub.docker.com/r/rancher/k3s/tags :D

Comment: I confirm that bitnami/elasticsearch now works since I've installed v1.21.2+k3s1. Thank you very much!